# What is the common term for Apache virtual hosts or Nginx block systems?

Tags: terminology, linux, nginx, apache-httpd

A webserver environment as with *Apache* or *Nginx* includes a type of file (or a file system) that I can call a *webserver substrate*; In Apache it is called a **Virtual host** and in Nginx I can call it a "Block system", mainly comprised of a `server{}` block, among other blocks.

This "webserver substratre" **connects** an app's directory with the webserver, and also enables or disables it (by means of webserver requests and responses associated with that app directory). Thus, each web application has one such substrate.

What is the common term for such file, or file system, in the *Linux System Administration* (LSA) field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All my searches for a term brought me to conclude that the general term either for one Apache virtual host file or a constellation of Nginx block files (each containing at least one block) is just that --- a virtual host.

Per project; either the virtual host (entity) is a single file or a combination of files, and that's true if the webserver software is different than these two.